# Navbar should be fix at the top

Tags: navbar, sticky

i have 2 headers in my website after scroll down the top header should hide and below navbar should become stick to the top that is it should be fixed at top..How to write code for this??Help me..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      // hide top menu
      // make bottom menu fixed
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      // show top menu
      // make bottom menu relative
    }
  });
});
```